# How to compute interpolant with new Z3?

Tags: interpolation, z3

I used to computing interpolant with `Z3_interpolate` function while using unstable Z3 4.3.2. But in the stable version of Z3 4.3.2 and unstable version of Z3 4.3.3, I cannot invoke `Z3_interpolate` any more. I am wondering how to compute interpolant with API provided by new Z3. (The document and example provide few information about computing interpolant with Z3 API and I don't know how to do it now)

Comment: I tried to use `Z3_mk_interpolant` and `Z3_compute_interpolant` and finally it returns a correct interpolant. But I am still worrying about safety of code because functions for interpolation are all in C API and I don't know when to use `Z3_inc_ref` and `Z3_dec_ref` to ensure memory safety. Can anyone provide a formal, safe way to compute interpolant using interpolation API of Z3?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, the interpolation API underwent some changes for the recent release and the code examples haven't been updated yet. Good to know that you did get it working in the end!

Comment: @cxcfan I'm facing a similar problem now, could you show how you have migrated the API call?

Comment: @GeorgeKarpenkov I wrote a simple function to compute the interpolant of two formulas.[(code)](http://lpaste.net/117015)

Comment: @cxcfan Thanks a lot! Do you know if it is still possible to use the normal `Z3_context` or do we have to create a special interpolation one?

Comment: @GeorgeKarpenkov Although document tells us to use `Z3_mk_interpoloation_context` for interpolation, by reading source code I found that this function just creates a normal context with `"MODEL"` and `"PROOF"` properties.

Comment: @cxcfan Thanks! For me it keeps returning the empty AST-vector, even though the result says UNSAT. Maybe I should open a new question.

Comment: @GeorgeKarpenkov This is how I compute interpolant with Z3 in my work. [(code)](http://lpaste.net/117072).